# Append option to multi-select using ajax

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, multi-select

I have the following HTML multi-select code:

```
<select class="multi-select" multiple="multiple" id="multiSelectId">
```

And am trying to dynamically add elements into it using ajax:

```
function TestFunction(value) {
  const selectMembers = $("#multiSelectId");
  selectMembers.empty();
  selectMembers.append('<option value="val">test1</option>');
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetMemberById", "SystemAdmin")',
    data: {
      'memberId': value
    },
    success: function(data) {
      selectMembers.append('<option value="val">test2</option>');
      alert("test3");
    }
  });
  selectMembers.multiSelect('refresh');
}
```

So the weird thing is, that test1 and test3 are working fine, whereas test2 doesn't work at all and I can't find why it doesn't work. Does anybody has an idea?

Comment: Have you tried to declare selectMembers as a var and not as a const? Maybe that's the problem

Comment: everything is working well [here](http://codepen.io/vilaskumkar/pen/YNmxKG), I've used dummy api for testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to refresh in the `success` callback handler. Remember `ajax()` is asynchronous.

```
function TestFunction(value) {
    const selectMembers = $("#multiSelectId");
    selectMembers.empty();
    selectMembers.append('<option value="val">test1</option>');
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetMemberById", "SystemAdmin")',
        data: {
            'memberId': value
        },
        success: function(data) {
            selectMembers.append('<option value="val">test2</option>');
            selectMembers.multiSelect('refresh');
            alert("test3");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Perfect! That has been the issue and thanks for the explanation as well!